# Excel - assign values based on the first unique item

Tags: excel

I have got an excel question that I can not answer. Here is my table:

```
  ID Key    Count Unique    Available   Text            Results
  1         0                           Text-1          Dupe-Y
  2         1               Y           Text-1          Y
  3         0                           Text-1          Dupe-Y
  4         0                           Text-1          Dupe-Y
  5         1               N           Text-2          N
  6         1               Y           Text-3          Y
  7         0                           Text-2          Dupe-N
  8         0   Duplicate               Text-2          Dupe-N
  9         0   Duplicate               Text-2          Dupe-N
  10        0   Y                       Text-2          Dupe-N
```

**Id Key** is just unique key.
**Count unique** picks up the first time each value in column **Text** appears. **Available** can have Y, N, Duplicate and **Text** is the main column I need to analyze my table. The **Results** are for the first time each value in **Text** appears (**Count unique = 1**), if there is a value in **Available** then that is the value I need, if **Count Unique** is 0 then is either Dupe-Y or Dupe-N depending on the value in **Available**.
I tried with a formula like this one but got stuck after initial progress. `=IF(B2=0,"",IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(D:D,D2)>1,IF(COUNTIF($D:$D,D2)=1,"",C2),1),1))`
Note that the column **Results** is the one I need to populate with a formula that is not affected by sorting or lack of it.

Comment: Of which column you got stuck and what error, can you elaborate more?

Comment: Results? I want to achieve it with a formula. Note: data won't be sorted.

Comment: Then update your question with a REAL input and your expected output

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got all those values and you just need a formula for column *Results*.

My formul will work only if the data is sorted like in your example. If sorting changes, formula will fail:

[image]

My formula is:

```
=IF(B2=1;D2;"Dupe-"&RIGHT(G1;1))
```

Comment: I cannot relay on the sorting. I need a formula that works in any case.

Comment: If the data is not sorted in any way, there is no way you can make when is the first time a text appears, because sorting changes this. There must be any correlation between fields to determine this